# What's the name (type) of redux function 'connect(mapStateToProps)(ConnectedList)'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am learing redux technology and I am stuck with understanfing of function connect, because the functions I have seen before take arguments, etc... and this one does not take anything at least it looks like that
 (code is working perfectly, i just can;t get the idea of function)

```
import React from "react"
import { connect } from "react-redux"

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return { root: state.root }
}

const ConnectedList = root => {
  console.log(root)
  return (
    <ul className="list-group list-group-flush">
      {root.root.articles.map(el => {
        return (
          <li className="list-group-item" key={el.id}>
            {el.title}
          </li>
        )
      })}
    </ul>
  )
}

const List = connect(mapStateToProps)(ConnectedList)

export default List
```

Comment: You can see the type definition here https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react-redux/v6/index.d.ts#L258

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It takes your `mapStateToProps` function, just like you called it--how is it not taking any parameters? You've passed one in.

https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect

It also takes additional parameters:

- `mapDispatchToProps`
- `mergeProps`
- `options`

(As detailed in the docs, which also list the types, if that's what you're really asking, but as it's not tagged TypeScript, and there's no TypeScript in your code, it's not entirely clear where you're coming from.)

`connect` (in this case) takes a single argument, a function, that maps the Redux state to your component's properties.

`connect` then returns a function which you call with `ConnectedList`, your component.

This is called a [Higher-Order Component (HOC)](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html), which is nothing more than a component (or component-like functionality) that wraps your component with code that does "things" then renders your component.

In this case, the HOC takes the Redux state you've specified in your `mapStateToProps` function and sends that state (as props) to your component, which it renders.

The [source code for `connect`](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/master/src/connect/connect.js#L52) shows how this works, although I suspect it will be a bit opaque at this point, until you're more familiar with JS and React.

---

```
const f = f1 => f2 => f1(f2)
const g1 = fn => { fn(); console.log(1) }
const g2 = () => console.log(2)
f(g1)(g2)
```

Or in more-relevant terminology:

```
const customConnect = aMappingFn => aComponent => aMappingFn(aComponent)

const yourMapper    = fn => { console.log(1); fn() }
const yourComponent = () => console.log(2)

customConnect(yourMapper)(yourComponent)
```

Comment: but this function looks not like connect(some arg), it looks like this connect()()

Comment: @Lucifer No, it looks like `connect(mapStateToProps)(ConnectedList)`, which is what you typed in. `mapStateToProps` is a parameter (that happens to be a function). `connect` in turn *returns* a function, which you're calling with the parameter `ConnectedList`, your component that `connect` is wrapping. This is a [Higher-Order Component (HOC)](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) which you will find all over the place in React.

Comment: If I do that way: const List = connect(mapStateToProps, ConnectedList), it gives me an error

Comment: @Lucifer Of course, because that's not how `connect` works. And that's not what you or I typed in.

Comment: But if it is a function why I cant just pass it like an normal argument connect( () => func() )

Comment: Can you please make a simple example of this function in your way like it will take a,b instead of mapStateToProps and ConnectedList and return sum of something it will defenetly make me understand it and soleve the problem

Comment: @Lucifer You could, but then you'd lose the ability to test `mapStateToProps` on its own, and the code would be that much harder to read.

Comment: @Lucifer I don't know what you're asking for an example of. In its simplest form (which this is) it takes a parameter (a function), and returns a function (a component) that wraps your component. The React docs I linked to explain HOCs and provide an example: that's all this is.

Comment: No you missunderstand me I here not for a ready code i want your implemetaion in the easiest way. Example: there is func(a) that return a let = a = (a) => return a, and i dont knwo how to make same with connect(mapStateToProps, ConnectedList)

Comment: Alright hold on as you said it takes a function, i will now implement something similar

Comment: @Lucifer Why do you want that? It would be a (local) function called `connect` that would take two parameters and do the exact same thing your existing code already does, except you'd have to rename the imported `connect`.

Comment: @Lucifer Your code will look *precisely* like your code does now, and do nothing more than obfuscate what's really happening.

Comment: let customConnect = (func, func2) => {
  return func2
};

let func = () => console.log(1);
let func2 = () => console.log(2);

customConnect(func)(func2); // Well, I've got an error :(

Comment: @Lucifer Because you're not doing it right--`customConnect` takes two funcs, you're passing in one. You also don't call *any* of the functions, you just pass them around and ignore them. See bottom of answer.

Comment: Oh my god I am soo sorry I hvave not notices your explanation and THANK you so much! I am sorry that i am so curios, i am just 16 and I want to learn everything deeply to understand what is going on , thanks again

Comment: @Lucifer Curiosity is a Good Thing; don't ever lose that. HOCs are fundamentally pretty simple (see the HOC docs), but as soon as you read someone *else's* code, particularly code that has to do a lot of things to work correctly, it gets fairly complicated fairly quickly. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

This is called currying. It's a functional programming paradigm that helps you abstract out otherwise repetitive logic. The connect function is basically a function that returns a function, this means you're able to pass parameters through to other functions. Here's a a great medium post that goes into further detail.

https://medium.com/javascript-scene/curry-and-function-composition-2c208d774983

Answer (score 0):

The `connect()` function connects a React component to a Redux store.

It does not modify the component class passed to it. instead, it returns a new, connected component class that wraps the component you passed in.

**Definition**

The `connect` function automatically takes the data from the `store`, and passes it down as `props` to the `connected component`. When the data in the `store` changes, the passed down `props` changes, and the component is automatically `re-rendered`. Cool!

In order to use your store in your container, You need to do two things:

**Firstly** : make use of `mapStateToProps()`. As the name suggests, it maps the state variables from your store to the props that you specify.

**Secondly** : You need to connect these props to your container. This is where `connect()` comes into picture. The object returned by the `mapStateToProps` component is connected to the container.

You can import connect from `react-redux` like

`import {connect} from 'react-redux';`

You can find the detailed doc [here](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect)

**Code Example**

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>{this.props.store_data}</div>;
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { store_data: state.appData };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App);
```